# Python3 problem with encoding german umlaute

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, encoding

I have a wierd issue with the encoding of strings. I have a string of unknown encoding, and checked via `type(string)` that it is indeed a string and not bytes.

When I do a `print(string)` my programm returns something like `'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6\xc3\x84\xc3\x9c\xc3\x96\xc3\x9f'` which are the `utf-8` encoded german umlaute `äüöÄÜÖß`.

Now in the python console I can do the following:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 13 2020, 07:46:32)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6\xc3\x84\xc3\x9c\xc3\x96\xc3\x9f'.encode('latin').decode('utf-8'))
äüöÄÜÖß
>>>
```

However this does not seem to work in my program using the same virtual environment.
Both `print('\xc3\xa4')` and `print('\xc3\xa4'.encode('latin').decode('utf-8'))` return the same.

Any ideas are welcome

*Kontext:* My Program reads messages from a Kafka broker, does some transformations and writes to a MySQL. There the wrongly encoded string ends up.

Comment: Define: "*this does not seem to work*".

Comment: It will be helpful to know what is there in your program. Please add that too. @Rudertier

Comment: @snakecharmerb Both outside and inside my venv I get ```echo $LANG ','  $LC_CTYPE ',' $LANG``` -> ```en_US.UTF-8 , , en_US.UTF-8```

Comment: Prefix your binary string with `b`. (it will not solve the problem, but please do not mix binary data with unicode string. If you want to write specific unicode characters, use `\uXXXX`.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I read the string from a function that returns a string, not a byte-string. Therfore I can not just prefix it. Thats the reason I tried the encoding and decoding.

Comment: But a function which return a string should not return `\x...`. So maybe your function return a read `\x..`, which Python should write it as `\\x..`? I'm confused by your comment

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I found the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. In the above code I had an explicit cast to a string. Where my byte-string was casted to a string thereby escaping all Unicode carachters. After changing this to a proper decoding everything works fine.